# Select (*) alternative - using jQuery datatables plugin

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, sql

I am using [jQuery dataTables plugin](https://datatables.net/) in a custom phonebook I have created for my organizations phonebook. The issue that I am having is that since I am using the `SELECT * from Table` command on a table with some 3000+ rows, dataTables wants to load the entire SQL table before loading and it causes the page to lag terribly. Is there a better way to do this? My reason for using dataTables is it has a custom jQuery search option which works beautifully.

I have tried using `SELECT TOP` but it will not return anything but the first hundred or however many specified.

Answer (score 0):

You can load partial data and use ajax to load more data when the user pages through the result. Have a look at the example they provide.

https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/pipeline.html

Answer (score 0):

Try AJAX paging, like Vlad says.

Also check out the `bDeferRender` option (look it up [here](https://datatables.net/ref)). If set to `true` you definitely experience faster page load. I dont know if that will be fast enough without server-side paging though. And what about the stress put on the DB?